# Send document file with Telegram library "canoe" for scala

Tags: scala, telegram-bot, telegram-api

im trying to figure it out, how can i download and upload java.io.File with canoe library.

https://github.com/augustjune/canoe

very poor documentation and a little bunch of examples. If someone know how to do this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

seems like i found a solution,

```
def filePrepareResponse[F[_]: TelegramClient](semaphore: Semaphore[F]): Scenario[F, Unit] = {
   val in: InputFile.Upload = InputFile.fromBytes("file.pdf", Files.readAllBytes(new File("/home/dmitry/Downloads/Обращение.PDF").toPath))
   for {
     chat <- Scenario.expect(command("download").chat)
     _    <- Scenario.eval(chat.send(DocumentContent(in)))
   } yield ()}
```

works for me